# how could I install a snap package via Ansible on an air-gapped system

Tags: ansible, offline, snapcraft

Installing snap packages via Ansible on systems that are connected to internet is rather simple. EG:

```
  - name: Install microk8s
    become: yes
    snap:
      name: microk8s
      classic: yes
      channel: "{{ microk8s_version }}"
```

Now I would need to do the same on a set of nodes that are air-gapped (no direct connection to internet).
I can do a 'snap download' for the required packages, and move them to the target machine(s).
But then how to do this in Ansible? Is there any support for this? Or do I have to use the shell/command module ?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this, but this method works with other modules.

```
  - name: install microk8s, file on local disk
    become: yes
    snap:
      name: /path/to/file
```

Comment: Right, it is possible to [to install the .snap application in an offline computer](https://askubuntu.com/a/775622/774046).

Comment: thx @Kevin C. I managed to get it working. I will add the code in a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

using the hint of @Kevin C I was able to solve the problem using the following playbook

```
  - name: copy microk8s snap to remote
    copy: 
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: "~/microk8s/"
      remote_src: no
    with_fileglob: 
      - "../files/microk8s/*"

  - name: snap ack the new package
    become: yes
    shell: |
       snap ack ~/microk8s/microk8s_1910.assert
       snap ack ~/microk8s/core_10583.assert

  - name: install microk8s, file on local disk
    become: yes
    snap:
      name: "~/microk8s/core_10583.snap"

  - name: install microk8s, file on local disk
    become: yes
    snap:
      name: "~/microk8s/microk8s_1910.snap"
      classic: yes
```

I hope this helps others also.
Would be nice to see this documented.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the packages onto the Ansible server, the following code will copy the file to the target(s). Something like the the following code should work.

```
  - name: copy files/local/microk8s.deb
    copy: 
      src: "files/local/microk8s.deb"
      dest: "~/microk8s.deb"
      remote_src: no
```

Where `files/` is at the same level as the playbook.

Comment: Thx. But that would still mean I need to do the 'install' through a 'shell: snap install microk8s.deb' and handle any issues around, right ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. While there is an [Ansible snap module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/snap_module.html) it doesn't appear to have an option to install from a local file. So that would need to be a shell command.